# C: socket binding on wrong port

Tags: c, sockets

I have C code that listens on a port, but it is listening on the wrong port.

This is defined in a .h file:

```
#define PHANTASIA_PORT 2101
```

The socket:

```
int the_socket, error, on=1;

    /* create a socket */
errno = 0;
if ((the_socket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {

    sprintf(error_msg,
       "[0.0.0.0:?] Socket creation failed in Do_init_server_socket: %s\n",
       strerror(errno));

    Do_log_error(error_msg);
    exit(SOCKET_CREATE_ERROR);
}

error = setsockopt(the_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
        (char *) &on, sizeof(on));
```

This is how it binds:

```
    /* set up the bind address */
bind_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
bind_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
bind_address.sin_port = PHANTASIA_PORT;

    /* bind to that socket */
error = bind(the_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &bind_address,
        sizeof(bind_address));
error = listen(the_socket, SOMAXCONN);
```

But then when it is run, lsof reports:

```
phantasia  2400     root    4u  IPv4 2024436       TCP *:13576 (LISTEN)
```

When I changed the port to 2100 in the define, it instead listened for:

```
phantasia  2266     root    4u  IPv4 2021315       TCP *:13320 (LISTEN)
```

This is some old code but doesn't have any warnings or errors when compiling. Maybe something is going over my head. I have a debug log when it binds and it reports it binds to port 2101.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `PHANTASIA_PORT` with `htons(PHANTASIA_PORT)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`htons`](http://www.retran.com/beej/htonsman.html) function when specifying the port number.

So this line:

```
bind_address.sin_port = PHANTASIA_PORT;
```

Should be:

```
bind_address.sin_port = htons(PHANTASIA_PORT);
```

`htons` is a function that will convert host integer numbers to network integer numbers, fixing the endianness (HI-LO/LO-HI byte order within integer) of them if necessary.

Comment: This is an absolutely horrid wart in the API, but it's never going away.

Comment: @wnoise: Agree 100%. Way back, some idiot decided saving one `bswap` opcode in kernelspace was worth polluting every userspace app ever to be written with ugly endian dependencies.

Comment: @wnoise @R.. Disagreed. If you're sending things over the network you already have to be aware of endianness, hiding it from the sockaddr_* users doesn't help anyone. (Though I'd concede that anyone sending a raw sockaddr_* struct, or any raw struct for that matter, over the network, should be kicked in the guts).

Comment: @ninjalj: The only things which should be sent over the network are text and binary files in standard file formats, which are pure octet sequences with no endian considerations. Sending and receiving C structures is an utterly backwards practice that should have been abolished 20 years ago. This leaves the `sockaddr` brain-damage as the only endian consideration in a decent modern program.